# Android view background make fit center

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using this code for setting background, is that possible to make it fit  center or prevent stretching

```
 toolbar_layout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);

 toolbar_layout.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
```

Comment: please explain properly by adding other details

Comment: `"... or prevent stretching "` - yes,  if you use `setGravity()` method

Comment: how to use setGavity() method ?

Comment: see [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#setGravity(int))

Comment: @pskink Which value shoud i give for setgravity(n)

Comment: `CENTER` for example

Comment: i set    mBitmapDrawable.setGravity(1); and it is working

Comment: do not use any hardcoded values like `1`, use the constants provided by java API like `CENTER`

Comment: Then how to make fitcenter like this             mBitmapDrawable.setGravity(CENTER);

Comment: there is no such gravity constant i'm afraid - `1` cannot work too as it is `CENTER_HORIZONTAL`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **apply image in the collapsing toolbar** then you should see their **official website** on [material design](https://material.io/develop/android/components/collapsing-toolbar-layout/).
Just go through it, you will get an idea.